# Web API 2: How to declare global-per-user variable that can be accessed in controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have Web API 2 (MVC) project. When any method is called, X-API-Key header is required. X-API-Key is used to distinguish between UAT and PROD/ Site and Mobile App calls.
I have a Message Handler, that validates X-API-Key and sets global-per-user variables before call reaches destination method, so these variables are available for any controller within the original call before any response sent. 
The main requirement is that global-per-user variables should be unique per user and can't be shared between method calls.
So static variables won't work, also tried to use HttpContext.Current.Cache and it doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

[MessageHandlers\APIKeyHandler.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1usY.png)

[SharedLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeaN0.png)

[CustomersController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIJ0.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: Can it just be a per-request variable? Why Global, and why per-user.  You usage in CustomersController looks like it's just being used on the current request anyways. Globals per-user is a major anti-pattern (what happens when you scale to multiple instances; etc)

Comment: Per request would mean that I need to Validate Client API Key (X-API-Key header) each time which I don't want to. Every call would go thru APIKeyHandler where I'd validate Client API Key (X-API-Key header) once, set up "global-per-user/call" variables, so I can use them in called method.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: From a security perspective, you do need to validate the key on *every* request (as you can't trust the client).  However, you could optimize that validation by having a cache of previously validated results. That cache could be a static variable, and you can clear it anytime and it would just get rebuilt.

Comment: Mike S: The problem with static variable is that it seems shared between users accessing the Web API. That's why it doesn't work for me as I need to cache/store it per user request.

Comment: That static is just for validating the header. Something like:
static _validHeaders = HashSet<string>(); 

lock(_validHeaders) {
if (_validHeaders.Contains(header)) { return true; }
   validateHeader(header); 

lock(_validHeaders) { 
   if (_validHeaders.Count > 100) { _validHeaders.Clear(); }
   _validHeaders.Add(header);
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for looking into it.

I believe I found what I was looking for:
[HttpContext.Current.Items](https://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx)

"Anything you place into the Items collection will only be around for the duration of a single web request, unlike the Session collection, which will keep it’s contents around for each user as long as they continue to make requests."

This is what I'm going to use for now:

Set "global-per-user" variable in SharedLibrary method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("EnableDebugMode", true);
```

Get "global-per-user" variable using SharedLibrary method:

```
public static bool GetEnableDebugMode()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("EnableDebugMode") ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Items["EnableDebugMode"] : false;
}
```

Use "global-per-user" variable in CustomersController:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    _r.ResponseCode = "002";
    if (UserSession.GetEnableDebugMode())
    {
        _r.ResponseBody = e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.Message + "  " + e.InnerException.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        _r.ResponseBody = e.Message;
    }
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, _r);
}
```